# Tesseract API ResultIterator error compil

Tags: c++, ocr, tesseract

I want to use `ResultIterator` from tesseract, I use the source give on APIExample like this:

```
Pix *image = pixRead("test.png");
tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
api->Init(NULL, "eng");
api->SetImage(image);
api->Recognize(0);
tesseract::ResultIterator* ri = api->GetIterator();
tesseract::PageIteratorLevel level = tesseract::RIL_WORD;
if (ri != 0) {
  do {
    const char* word = ri->GetUTF8Text(level);
    float conf = ri->Confidence(level);
    int x1, y1, x2, y2;
    ri->BoundingBox(level, &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2);
    printf("word: '%s';  \tconf: %.2f; BoundingBox: %d,%d,%d,%d;\n",
           word, conf, x1, y1, x2, y2);
    delete[] word;
  } while (ri->Next(level));
}
```

But I have this error when I compile:

```
ocr.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
ocr.cpp:82:34: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class tesseract::ResultIterator’
In file included from ocr.cpp:10:0:
/usr/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:83:7: error: forward declaration of ‘class tesseract::ResultIterator’
ocr.cpp:83:28: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class tesseract::ResultIterator’
In file included from ocr.cpp:10:0:
/usr/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:83:7: error: forward declaration of ‘class tesseract::ResultIterator’
 ocr.cpp:85:15: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class tesseract::ResultIterator’
In file included from ocr.cpp:10:0:
/usr/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:83:7: error: forward declaration of ‘class tesseract::ResultIterator’
ocr.cpp:89:20: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class tesseract::ResultIterator’
In file included from ocr.cpp:10:0:
/usr/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:83:7: error: forward declaration of ‘class tesseract::ResultIterator’
```

My version of `tesseract-ocr-dev` is 3.02.01-6 and version of `libtesseract-dev` is 3.02.01-6

Comment: You must `#include` the definition of `class tesseract::ResultIterator`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Field has incomplete type" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466055/field-has-incomplete-type-error)

Comment: I have include `#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>` it is not enough ? @Paolo M